# Running command in docker container results in directly shutting down the docker container

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, docker-container

Im currently struggling to run a container and execute a command within this container.I'm trying to use NanoSNP (https://github.com/huangnengCSU/NanoSNP), which is an image available from dockerhub. After fulling this docker, the following command would be sufficient to run the the container:

```
docker run \
-v "${INPUT_DIR}":"${INPUT_DIR}" \
-v "${OUTPUT_DIR}":"${OUTPUT_DIR}" \
--gpus all \
huangnengcsu/nanosnp:v2.1-gpu \
run_caller.sh \
-b "${INPUT_DIR}/input.bam" \
-f "${INPUT_DIR}/reference.fa" \
-t "${THREADS}" \
-c "${COVERAGE}" \
-o "${OUTPUT_DIR}"
```

What i've been using to start the docker is the following:

```
docker run\
    -v "/home/stanaanhane/anaconda3/envs/SNPcalling/Code_SNP":"/home/stanaanhane/anaconda3/envs/SNPcalling/Code_SNP"\
        -v "$home/stanaanhane/anaconda3/envs/SNPcalling/Data":"/home/stanaanhane/anaconda3/envs/SNPcalling/Data"\
            huangnengcsu/nanosnp:v2.1-gpu \
                run_caller.sh\
                    --bam_fn=/home/stanaanhane/anaconda3/envs/SNPcalling/Code_SNP/BRCA1_MAP.sorted.bam\
                        --ref_fn=/home/stanaanhane/anaconda3/envs/SNPcalling/Code_SNP/BRCA1.fasta\
                            --output=/home/stanaanhane/anaconda3/envs/SNPcalling/Data\
                                --threads==10\
                                    --coverage==1
```

But when started, I see the docker container starting, but almost directly stop. The `docker ps -a` looks like this:

```
99cd4e272f19   huangnengcsu/nanosnp:v2.1-gpu   "/bin/bash"   19 hours ago   Exited (0) 18 hours ago               snp
446add2244e4   ubuntu                          "bash"        19 hours ago   Exited (137) 18 hours ago             festive_kirch
013d00f65681   hello-world                     "/hello"      23 hours ago   Exited (0) 23 hours ago               upbeat_cannon
78481d30f8a0   hello-world                     "/hello"      23 hours ago   Exited (0) 23 hours ago               loving_mclean
1aba1e8fa496   hello-world                     "/hello"      23 hours ago   Exited (0) 23 hours ago               admiring_visvesvaraya
```

I've tried looking around, but can't find the solution. If anyone has a suggestion, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you do `docker logs snp`, edit your post and add the output to your post, please?

Comment: What is in the image's Dockerfile?  Does it have an `ENTRYPOINT` line that would cause the command to be interpreted differently?

Comment: @HansKilian Unfortunally when I try that, there is no output. I tried using the container id instead of `huangnengcsu/nanosnp:v2.1-gpu` and this is what is shown `Unable to find image 'd4cc5447c631:v2.1-gpu' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for d4cc5447c631, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.`

Comment: From the output from `docker ps -a`, it looks like your container has run `/bin/bash` which would indicate that it wants to be run interactively. So adding `-it` as `docker run` options might work. Remember to put `-it` before the image name in the command.

Comment: @HansKilian So what I did is, `-it huangnengcsu/nanosnp:v2.1-gpu`, and the place shown in de code above. Unfortunately, nothing changed. With the docker plugin in VSC, I can see that it goes straight to the "red box" instead of going to the "green triangle" first.